# Quantification of entropy mathematically when $T$ and $V$ both change

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy, volume

[image]

$$ln\frac{W_f}{W_i}=N ln\frac{V_f}{V_i}=n N_a ln\frac{V_f}{V_i}$$
$$\Delta S=nRln\frac{V_f}{V_i}$$ 
$$ln\frac{V_f}{V_i}=\frac{1}{n N_a}ln\frac{W_f}{W_i}$$
$$\Delta S=\frac{R}{N_a}ln\frac{W_f}{W_i}=kln\frac{W_f}{W_i}=klnW_f-klnW_i$$
hence  $$S=klnW$$

For T change taken from Atkins physical chemistry:

[image]

Above micro entropy S=klnW and macro entropy $\Delta S=\frac{\Delta Q}{T}$ are united isolated for T and V change. Entropy being a state function my problem is how one can understand that this is the $quantification$ that works for paths in change of both V and T? How does T and V quantify against each other? Can this be justified or explained?

Comment: Please do not post images of equations. Images are bad because 1) The links can go bad, 2) They're not searchable, and 3) They're not editable. Please use mathjax to type all equations in your posts on Physics Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me the first derivation is simply assuming that S = k ln W, because it looks like it was inserted along the way and then pulled out at the end as if it was a conclusion of the logic.  What's more, by considering only position and not momentum, it seems to me that derivation is assuming the particles are not changing kinetic energy.  So that's why it ends up looking like there's no explicit mention of heat input or dQ/T, because to change V but not change kinetic energy, there would need to be heat input that is implicit.  The second derivation shows more clearly where the connection between dQ/T and k ln W comes from, but it does it only for constant volume.  But a reversible change in V does not change the entropy, so as long as everything is done reversibly, it doesn't matter if V changes or not, and the second derivation is less general than it could be.

Comment: the first derivation introduces macro $\Delta S$ and afterwards uses the earlier derivation in the first part to alter macro $\Delta S$ to micro $\Delta S$. It does not assume that S=klnW. My problem is how to justify quantification with change in both T and V basically because entropy governs spontanity.

Comment: In any event, look more closely at the assumptions being made in the first derivation, particularly what is being assumed about what is happening to the temperature.   In short, the first derivation makes more assumptions than it specifies, and the second makes more assumptions than it requires.

Answer (score 0):

For stable pressure it is ΔS= nCplnTf/Ti= nCplnVf/Vi (Cp=molecular specific heat)
To quantify,we set initial values Ti=1=Vi and derive: S= nCplnT = nCplnV